# Mutability of core functions in Racket

Tags: racket, mutability

I came across a rather unexpected behavior today, and it utterly contradicted what (I thought) I knew about mutability in Racket.

```
#lang racket

(define num 8)
;(define num 9)
```

Uncommenting the second line gives back the error `"module: duplicate definition for identifier in: num"`, which is fine and expected.  After all, `define` is supposed to treat already defined values as immutable.

However, this makes no sense to me:

```
#lang racket

(define num 8)
num
(define define 1)
(+ define define)
```

It returns `8` and `2`, but...

1. `define` is not `set!`, and should not allow the redefinition of something already defined, such as `define` itself.
2. `define` is a core language feature, and is clearly already defined, or I should not be able to use `num` at all.

What gives?  Why is `define`, which is used to create immutable values, not immutable to itself?  *What is happening here?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a top-level definition binds an identifier that originates from a macro expansion, the definition captures only uses of the identifier that are generated by the same expansion due to the fresh scope that is generated for the expansion.

In other words, the transformers (macros) that are required from other modules can be re-defined because they're expanded out by the macro expander (so the issue is not quite about mutability) Moreover, since racket is all about extensibility, there are no reserved keywords and additional functionality can be added to the current `define` through a macro (or a function) - that's why it can be redefined.

`define` is defined as macro of this form - see [here](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/6073602c8e44fec3d7ca04d0d4fe2eb41a61ab23/racket/collects/racket/private/define.rkt#L27).

```
#lang racket

(module foo1 racket
  (provide foo1)
  (define-syntaxes (foo1)
    (let ([trans (lambda (syntax-object)
                          (syntax-case syntax-object ()
                            [(_) #'1]))])
      (values trans))))

; ---

(require 'foo1)


(foo1)
; => 1

(define foo1 9)


(+ foo1 foo1)
; => 18
```

Comment: Could you break up that first sentence a little? I'm having a lot of trouble following what you've written.

Comment: The transformers (macros) that are required from other modules can be re-defined because they're expanded out by the macro expander (so the issue is not quite about mutability) Moreover, since racket is all about extensibility, there are no reserved keywords and additional functionality can be added to the current `define` through a macro (or a function) - that's why it can be redefined.

Comment: That makes sense now, thank you so much!  I edited the answer to integrate the comment, and will accept the answer once the edit goes through.  After that, these comments can probably be deleted.  Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2):

```
(define define 1)
```

This example shows shadowing, which is different from mutation.

Shadowing allocates new locations in memory. It does not mutate existing ones.

Concretely, the new `define` shadows the `define` from Racket.

All languages with a notation of local scope allow shadowing, eg:

```
> (define x 10)
> (define (f x) ; x shadowed in function f
    (displayln x) 
    (set! x 2) ; (local) x mutated
    (displayln x))
> (f 1)
1
2
; local x is out of scope now
> (displayln x) ; original x unmutated
10
```

For the other example,

```
(define num 8)
;(define num 9)
```

this demonstrates that you cant shadow something within the same scope, which is also standard in other languages, eg:

```
> (define (g x x) x) ; cant have two parameters named x
```

Comment: Is there a way to reference the larger scoped `define` (such as `this` in Java) once the local scoping had been created?

Comment: No, but you can always re-import the original with a different name, eg `(require (prefix-in r: racket/base)) (r:define x 10)`